# (BST) Error: No matching overloaded function found

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I just started learning Binary Search Trees. I have been trying to fix a couple of errors since yesterday. I looked at the reference links but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The example below was copied from one of the slideshows provided to us by the lecturer but when I run it, I get the following errors:

> [C2672](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2672?view=msvc-160): 'Insert': no matching overloaded function found

> [C2784](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2784?view=msvc-160): 'void Insert(TreeNode *&,ItemType)': could not deduce template argument for 'TreeNode *&' from 'ItemType *'

Any help would be appreciated.

**BinaryTree.h**

```
#pragma once
using namespace std;

template<class ItemType>
struct TreeNode
{
    ItemType info;
    ItemType* left;
    ItemType* right;
};

template<class ItemType>
class TreeType
{
public:
    TreeType();
    ~TreeType();    

    void InsertItem(ItemType item);

private:
    TreeNode<ItemType>* root;
};

template<class ItemType>                 
void Insert(TreeNode<ItemType>*& tree, ItemType item) // helper function
{
    if (tree == NULL)
    { // insertion place found
        tree = new TreeNode<ItemType>;
        tree->right = NULL;
        tree->left = NULL;
        tree->info = item;
    }
    else if (item < tree->info)
        Insert(tree->left, item); // insert in left subtree
    else
        Insert(tree->right, item); // insert in right subtree
}
template<class ItemType>                 
void TreeType<ItemType>::InsertItem(ItemType item) // member function
{
    Insert(root, item);
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "BinaryTree.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    TreeType<int> MyTree;
    MyTree.InsertItem(9);
}
```

Comment: Side notes: `using namespace std;` is [always a risky choice at global scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), but it is particularly nasty in a header because it forces that risky choice on everyone including the header. You also want your headers to be internally consistent. BinaryTree.h lacks [a header that defines `NULL`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL), forcing an unnecessary ordering on files that include it. This leads to mystery bugs. Code works, someone makes an inconsequential change, and gets errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```cpp
template<class ItemType>
struct TreeNode
{
    ItemType info;
    ItemType* left;
    ItemType* right;
};
```

`left` and `right` are pointers to the data being stored in the `TreeNode`, not pointers to `TreeNode`s.

Instead use

```cpp
template<class ItemType>
struct TreeNode
{
    ItemType info;
    TreeNode* left;
    TreeNode* right;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. It seems that there was a typo in my lecture notes. Your suggestions fixed the errors.

Comment: Smurf happens, @Joe . To be honest this answer only exists because when I called this out as "typo-ish" in a comment, I was worried about the comment not being clear enough.